# Changing the format of the entire column in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a mysql table like this:

```
Testtag
SG_QRA_SGBAKE_0012
SG_QRA_SGBAKE_0013
SG_QRA_SGHAST_0005
SG_QRA_SGHAST_0006
SG_QRA_SGHAST_0007
```

and I want to change the entire column to like this:

```
Testtag
SGBAKE.0012
SGBAKE.0013
SGHAST.0005
SGHAST.0006
SGHAST.0007
```

I am stuck here. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can handle your requirement using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` along with `REPLACE`:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET Testtag = REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Testtag, '_', -2), '_', '.');
```

If you just want to *view* your data this way, then use this query:

```sql
SELECT Testtag, REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Testtag, '_', -2), '_', '.') AS NewTag
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a469abc621b93e7cfc845960535a90b3).